# Bootstrap 3 email validation without form

Tags: validation, email, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have a text field to input email. Based on the email inputted, href of 2 anchor tags are need to be generated. So I need to validate the input field without a form or submit. Or the email should be validated on clicking the link. I also need the email validation popover of bootstrap 3.

[Reference](http://willofthepeopleapp.com)

The 2 links are the images below the text field.

Comment: I don't get the problem. Validate the field onblur ?

Comment: ok, thats fine. How to do it?

Comment: Well to start with, what validator are you using? With jQuery Validation Plugin it would be something like `$('input').blur(function() { if $(this).valid()) { alert('do something!'); } }); ` but to help you you need to add some code.

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3 and it has built in validator

Comment: Can you verify that? There is no trace of a validation script at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/ In the forms section. Pls try

Comment: Those are styles that Bootstrap is providing for you that you can use to highlight validation errors, but you are going to need a separate JS library to actually do the validation. I would suggest something like http://jqueryvalidation.org/, which can be made to play very nicely with Bootstrap's validation styles.